# Sort an array of integers without affecting indexes of a special character denoted by $

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I have been asked a question in interview as below.
For example: Input Array of Integers including special character any special character like #,@,$ exists at few indexs of input array:

```
[12,5,65,#,@,20,10,#,@,47,50,$,11,$,90,$]. Here, we have special character denoted as $ exists at index 5, 8 & 10.
```

After sorting, special character position (index) should not changed.It means output array should look like below:

[5, 10, 11, #,@,12, 20, #,@, 47, 50, $, 65, $, 90,$]

My answer was: split array into sub arrays on basis of $. After that, Sort all subArray separately and then, merge them. But, interviewers were not so impressed. Please suggest different approach.

Comment: $ position should not get changed means? they should remain at that index or they should remain before the numbers they are currently? Spilling them and sorting will only sort items in sub-array level and not globally.

Comment: Why weren't they happy?

Comment: If you sort the subarrays only that means that you didn't sort the entire array in the correct order. Also, doing sorting without using sorting algorithms does not make any sense whatsoever, since any code that does sorting is by definition a (description of a) sorting algorithm.

Comment: It is *impossible* to sort the data without using any sorting algorithms. Even if you don't use a built-in `sort()` method from the Java Runtime Library, and implement your own sorting, you'd still be using a sorting algorithm. Any time you write code, you implement an [**Algorithm**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/algorithm?s=t): *a set of rules for solving a problem in a finite number of steps*.

Comment: @Andreas : They meant, "don't use inbuilt sorting algorithm directly but, implement your own logic."

Comment: @NishuNishant Then they should have said so. Programming is all about *accurately* specifying what you want to happen. If you can't even specify the requirements accurately, before you start coding, then you're already doing it wrong, and it'll be impossible to verify the result.

Comment: @NishuNishant *Don't use any sorting algorithms* you mean inbuilt sorting algo ?? If yes, then anyway you can't achieve this using inbuilt sorting algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could do it with Streams.

1. First you remember where the dollar signs were
2. Then you remove the dollar signs
3. Then you sort the list
4. Then you add the dollar signs back in

```
private static List<Object> list = 
    Arrays.asList(12, 5, 65, 20, 10, "$", 47, 50, "$", 11, "$", 90);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> dollarIndices = 
            IntStream.range(0, list.size()).filter(i -> list.get(i).equals("$")).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> noDollars = 
            list.stream().filter(Integer.class::isInstance).map(Integer.class::cast)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.sort(noDollars);
    List<Object> withDollars = new ArrayList<>(noDollars);
    dollarIndices.stream().forEach(i -> withDollars.add(i, "$"));

    System.out.println(withDollars);
}
```

Output:

```
[5, 10, 11, 12, 20, $, 47, 50, $, 65, $, 90]
```

Comment: Cool. We thought of same algo ! :) thumbs up!

Comment: Question title says *"without affecting special characters"*. Just because the **example** only uses `"$"` for the special characters, doesn't mean that it is the only kind that needs to be excluded. Solution is oversimplified, making a baseless assumption.

Comment: Also, question is about an input *array*, and a output *array*. Would be nice if answer matches question.

Comment: @Andreas The input is actually an array (see Arrays.asList) but in any case we can expect the OP to adapt the solution to specific needs. This is not a work-for-hire site; my Java solution illustrates the algorithm steps that I provided at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

One of the simplest sorting **algorithms** is the [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), which is perfect for this, as it can easily skip elements that should be left alone.

```
private static void sortIntegers(Object[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] instanceof Integer) {
            int minIdx = i;
            int min = (Integer) array[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[j] instanceof Integer && (Integer) array[j] < min) {
                    minIdx = j;
                    min = (Integer) array[j];
                }
            }
            if (minIdx != i) {
                array[minIdx] = array[i];
                array[i] = min;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
Object[] array = {12,5,65,20,10,"$",47,50,"$",11,"$",90};
sortIntegers(array);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

*Output*

```
[5, 10, 11, 12, 20, $, 47, 50, $, 65, $, 90]
```

Comment: That's a nice solution

Comment: Good solution. You can do the same thing with insertion sort and bubble sort. Quicksort, too, although the logic is a bit more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Algo to solve this question

- Store the index of special string/characters. here it's $- Array1
- Get all the  integer elements of array and sort. - Array 2
- Insert the special string(here it's $) of Array1 and merge with Array2. Make sure index doesn't change of Array1 element.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the entries while iterating the array and put an if else condition for skipping the dollar signs.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's another solution**:

- Keep a set of the all the possible indices that contain a `$` character.
- Store a separate list containing only numbers, so we can sort it later.
- Once all the numbers are added, sort them all separately.
- Loop over the original lists indices, and if the current index exists in the set of indices, add a `$` to the resultant array list. Otherwise, add and remove first number from the sorted numbers.

**Example Code:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class SpecialSort {

    private static String DOLLAR_SIGN = "$";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(
                          Arrays.asList(12, 5, 65, 20, 10, "$", 47, 50, "$", 11, "$", 90));

        Set<Integer> dollarSigns = new HashSet<>();
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Object current = list.get(i);
            if (current.equals(DOLLAR_SIGN)) {
                dollarSigns.add(i);
            } else {
                numbers.add((Integer)current);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(numbers);

        List<Object> sorted = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (dollarSigns.contains(i)) {
                sorted.add(DOLLAR_SIGN);
            } else {
                sorted.add(numbers.remove(0));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sorted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ javac SpecialSort.java && java SpecialSort
[5, 10, 11, 12, 20, $, 47, 50, $, 65, $, 90]
```